# i would want to know how to take char input with spaces in Java?

Tags: java

I want to take `char` or `character` input from the user, with spaces in Java.
I have tried

```
String output = "Java"; //this only when I like declare a string a string.
```

My knowledge is very limited in Java, any help would be very much appreciated.
thanks!
i would want to know how to take the users input in char u guys are telling me how to do it int and all but what i was asking was
`String input = "Be in present";`
and please don't Spam me with crap like how to construct a Scanner or how its already there since i have been looking through the forum and it does'nt answer my question in specific like

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
char c = reader.nextChar();
```

since most of this stuff does not work and these methods are invalid.

Comment: Or read Oracle's Java Tutorial, or any Java text book, or Java beginner's video.

Comment: `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);`  That's a pretty strong hint, just in case you couldn't find what it was that read command-line input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `reader.ReadLine()` to read the full line of user input and do what you want later in the code. For example put all **chars** into an array.

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = reader.ReadLine();
char[] c = input.toCharArray();
```

Comment: thanks mate i am sorry for being mean and please don't be offended bros if i did'nt thank anybody else and also thank you @Tomaltach it was helpful and now my code works so thanks again